# Haunted Trackpad Pointer When Hard Drive Is Active

Tags: mouse, touchpad

I recently installed ubuntu 14.04 on an Hp Compaq NC6400 I am rehabbing, in order to test the machine.  The hard drive I installed into the computer worked fine and had Windows Vista loaded on it.  Upon loading Ubuntu onto the machine the pointer for the touchpad started acting erratically.  It tends to pull to the upper left of the screen.  I have been checking forums for a series of hours already, and tried a series of fixes already and none of them have worked.  During this process I started to notice that the pull only happened when the hard drive activity indicator light is on.  This seems to lead to the conclusion that the problem has something to do with the magnetic energy being generated by the hard drive in relation to the trackpad, but that conclusion is problematic due to the perfect functioning of the trackpad pointer when the computer was running Vista.  Can someone possibly lead me to some possible solution to this problem?

Comment: Can you document what you have done so far, so suggest answers don't duplicate your effort